# How to save generated PDF with Reportlab to Datastore in App Engine Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf, google-cloud-datastore, reportlab

I have a method that generates a PDF file using Reportlab library:

```
def obtenerPDFNuevoPedido(self, handler,rsUsuarioPedido, rsPedido):
    handler.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    handler.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
    story = []
    story.append(Paragraph('CHIPAS', ParagraphStyle(name="centeredStyle", alignment=TA_CENTER, fontSize=20)))
    story.append(Paragraph('____________ENLANUBE', ParagraphStyle(name="centeredStyle", alignment=TA_CENTER, fontSize=20)))
    story.append(Spacer(6, 22))
    story.append(Table([[Paragraph(str(strftime("%Y-%m-%d", gmtime())), ParagraphStyle(name="centeredStyle", alignment=TA_LEFT, fontSize=7)), 
    Paragraph(str(strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())), ParagraphStyle(name="centeredStyle", alignment=TA_RIGHT, fontSize=7))]],colWidths=[5.05 * cm, 3.1 * cm]))
    story.append(Paragraph("DEVELOPED AT ROSHKA-LABS", ParagraphStyle(name="centeredStyle", alignment=TA_CENTER, fontSize=6)))
    story.append(Paragraph('-'*50, styleCentered))
    #...
    #...
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(handler.response.out, pagesize=letter)
    doc.build(story)
```

when I call that method, it opens a save dialog, where I can specify where the file should be saved.

How shoud I do to save the generated pdf file in the Datastore?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) You can specify only desired file name (not destination)

2) Try this (not tested)

```
#define your database structure
from google.appengine.ext import db

class PdfStorage(db.Model): 
   timeAdded = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
   pdfContent = db.BlobProperty()
```

---

Replace your

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(handler.response.out, pagesize=letter)
doc.build(story)
```

with

```
pdf = StringIO()


doc = SimpleDocTemplate(pdf, pagesize=letter)
doc.build(story) 

#get content of generated pdf
content = pdf.getvalue()

#save to db
pdfStorage = PdfStorage(pdfContent = content);
pdfStorage.put()

#output to browser 
handler.response.write(content)
```

Comment: Thanks russenreaktor! I edited two lines of your answer =). It works like charm!.